# Numeração de linhas MYSQL apresentando sequência errada

Tags: mysql

Simplificando, Tenho duas tabelas, `perguntas` e `respostas`, para cada `pergunta` `4` ou mais `respostas`, acontece que não estou conseguindo `numerar` as `linhas` corretamente quando agrupo por perguntas.

> Meu resultado:

```
| linha |          pergunta | resposta |
|-------|-------------------|----------|
|     1 |  Qual o seu nome? |     gino |
|     5 | Qual a sua idade? |       20 |
```

> Pretendido:

```
| linha |          pergunta | resposta |
|-------|-------------------|----------|
|     1 |  Qual o seu nome? |     gino |
|     2 | Qual a sua idade? |       20 |
```

> Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `perguntas` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `pergunta` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL

);

INSERT INTO `perguntas` (`id`, `pergunta`) VALUES
(1,'Qual o seu nome?'),
(2,'Qual a sua idade?');

CREATE TABLE `respostas` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `pergunta_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `resposta` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL

);

INSERT INTO `respostas` (`id`,`pergunta_id`,`resposta`) VALUES
(1,1,'gino'),
(2,1,'lato'),
(2,1,'sapo'),
(2,1,'dode'),

(1,2,'20'),
(2,2,'30'),
(2,2,'40'),
(2,2,'50');
```

> Consulta:

```
Select    @contador := @contador + 1 AS linha,
pergunta, resposta from (SELECT @contador := 0) AS nada,
 perguntas p

inner join respostas r on r.pergunta_id=p.id

group by p.id
```

Comment: Não tem lógica isso `from (SELECT @contador := 0)`

Comment: Porque não tem lógica?

Comment: peguei esse código por aqui mesmo

Comment: Na verdade esse select faz um rolo, usando o contador como tabela, e fazendo `group by p.id`.

Comment: @rbz `(SELECT @contador := 0)` serve para iniciar o contador com zero quando você não pode fazer um `SET @contador := 0;` separado. Normalmente o `SET` fica mais legivel e simples de manter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente por *subquery*:

```
SET @n = 0;

SELECT @n := @n+1 AS linha, tab.*
FROM (SELECT pergunta, resposta 
FROM perguntas p
INNER JOIN respostas r ON r.pergunta_id=p.id) as tab;
```

Funcionando no [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gva9Lt2B29HzhNisLB977v/0)

Comment: recebo esse erro:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM (SELECT pergunta, resposta) FROM perguntas p INNER JOIN respostas r ON r' at line 1

Comment: Alterado.......

Comment: Esse resultado eu já conseguia, preciso agrupar por pergunta

Comment: Como você vai agrupar por pergunta se a resposta é diferente? São vários registros. N:N.

Comment: Gostaria apenas de numerar as questões neste gerador de provas:
http://educar.esy.es/gerarProvas/

Comment: Você teria que gerar por 2 partes então. Primeiro a pergunta e depois as respostas. Repetição de respostas dentro da repetição de perguntas. Ou vc gera somente as perguntas e usa o contador, ou foi como fiz. Se não, não teria como separar as respostas depois. Ou trazer agrupado por `GROUP_CONCAT()` e fazer um `explode` depois.

Comment: isso eu já fiz, criei uma view para perguntas e outra para respostas com group_concat, mas mesmo assim está contando errado as linha.

Comment: Resolvi, eu estava usando o group_concat para as `respostas`, na própria pesquisa, bastou criar uma view separada para resolver.

Comment: Pena que negativaram minha pergunta

Comment: Positivei! Resolvido! rs

Comment: Vlw mesmo cara!